# Elasticbeanstalk .ebextensions/xx.config is not exeuted

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having a project repo, whose root directory has .ebextensions dir with following env.config file (it is JSON, I also tried in YAML format).

{"option_settings":[{"option_name":"TEST_KEY","value":"test_key"}]}

Now the issue is, when I do eb deploy (after git add/commit), I see the .ebextensions dir with env.config is copied to /var/app/current, but the config is not updated in the base image.

The cfn-init.log does not show up that the env.config file is read/used. Snippet of the log,

```
    2015-02-12 22:40:10,264 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
    2015-02-12 22:40:10,265 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
    2015-02-12 22:40:10,265 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
```

I am just breaking my head over here.

Comment: Option setting require a namespace attribute. Have you read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-options ?